# updateOrCreate to change foreign key and if he don't exist, drop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these three tables: `Class`, `Schedules` and `Attendance`.

A professor selects the schedules a student missed to record attendance. To do that he uses checkboxes which will return the `student_id`, the `class_id` and `schedule_id`. Every time the professors changes the attendance, it is necessary to change the `schedule_id`.

The problem is when he casts the non-attendance (*"This student missed my class in this schedule"*) but want to revert it afterward (*"This student don't missed the class in this schedule, my mistake"*), the professor will remove the attendance and the `schedule_id` needs to be dropped.

So, I need a way to find a way to drop the foreign key if I don't have a schedule_id on the request in the `updateOrCreate` method.

The controller which casts the attendance:

```
foreach ($attendances as $f){
    $class->attendances()->updateOrCreate(
          [
              'class_id' => $f['class_id'],
              'student_id' => $f['student_id'],
          ],[                    [
               'schedule_id' => $f,
          ]
    );
}
```

The Class model:

```
public function attendances()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);
}
```

Relations:

```
Class->hasMany->attendances(). Attendances->hasMany->schedules.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the value of your checkbox you can set the required action for this usecase.

```
if (Request::get('mycheckbox')) {
    // got schedule_id 
    // Insert/Update Record
} else {
   // Don't have schedule_id
   // Delete Record
   Schedules::destroy($id);
}
```

If you just want to update the many to many table by deleting all id's that are not listed in the request anymore use `sync`. Documentation Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models -> Section **Syncing Associations**

> You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table.